# Using ngContent within ngFor for different objects

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular2-ngcontent

I have a component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.html'
})
export class MyComponentComponent {

  @Input() values;    
}

<div *ngFor="let value of values">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

When using the component I want the template of the div to be passed into the component so it can be used with different object types.

```
<app-my-component [values]="myVals">      
   <div>{{value.name}}</div>
   <div>{{value.age}}</div>
   <div>{{value.address}}</div>
</app-my-component>

<app-my-component [values]="myDifferentVals">      
   <div>{{value.company}}</div>
   <div>{{value.phone}}</div>
   <div>{{value.email}}</div>
</app-my-component>
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: What is the necessity for this? IMO, As you are only trying to print string values, you can either provide only the string[] to your component or use *ngFor within <app-my-component> tag

Comment: I will be passing more. I only used this as an example

Answer (score 0):

ng-content allows you to render parent component's content "inside" a child component.

```
<app-my-component>    
   <div *ngFor="let value of myVals">  
     <div>{{value.name}}</div>
     <div>{{value.age}}</div>
     <div>{{value.address}}</div>
   <div>
</app-my-component>
```

passing an array to a child, then enumerating it in the parent. might as well enumerate it in the parent directly. so no, it doesn't work the way, it seems to me, that you intended it to.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible ways to do this:

**1) Iterating over your array in parent component**

In this case, passing array as Input may not be required. That depends on your requirement and implementation.

```
<app-my-component>    
   <ng-container *ngFor="let value of myVals">  
     <div>{{value.name}}</div>
     <div>{{value.age}}</div>
     <div>{{value.address}}</div>
   <ng-container>
</app-my-component>



 <app-my-component> 
    <ng-container *ngFor="let value of myDifferentVals">     
      <div>{{value.company}}</div>
      <div>{{value.phone}}</div>
      <div>{{value.email}}</div>
    </ng-container>
 </app-my-component>
```

**2) Iterating over your array in child component only.**

Component where my-component is used,

```
    <app-my-component [values]="myVals" [keys]=['name','age','address']>
    </app-my-component>

    <app-my-component [values]="myDifferentVals" [keys]=['company','phone','email']>          
    </app-my-component>
```

In my-component,

```
    @listOfKeys: string[] = [];

    <div *ngFor="let value of values">
      <div *ngFor="let key of keys">
          {{value[key]}}
      </div>         
    </div>
```